# if $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n^2\ln{(n+1)}}$,show that $f$ is differentiable on $x=-1$ and $x=1?$..

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

let $$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^n}{n^2\ln{(n+1)}},-1\le x\le 1$$

prove

$f$ is differentiable on $x=-1$ and $x=1?$..

for this problem I want show 
$f(x)$ is uniform convergence?

maybe
$$|\dfrac{x^n}{n^2\ln{(n+1)}}|\le\dfrac{1}{n^2\ln{(n+1)}}?$$
then I can't Continue,Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\lvert\frac{x^{n}}{n^{2}\ln(n+1)}\rvert\le\frac{1}{n^{2}}$

for $n\ge2$ for uniform convergence. $f$ is the uniform limit of continuous functions for continuity.

Comment: oh,Thank you.But how show $f$ is  differentiable on $x=1?$

Comment: You're welcome. Since $f$ is uniformly convergent then the derivative of the series is the series of the derivatives for $x\in(-1,1)$. Using Abel's Theorem and the Alternating Series Theorem we find that $f$ is differentiable at $x=-1$. $f$ is not differentiable at $x=1$ by Abel's Theorem again since the derivative series is infinite at $x=1$.